# How to load aspx inside content or update panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, aspmenu

Sorry for this pretty simple question: I have a Master Page with a menu located at left, and an update panel inside a ContentPlaceHolder located at right.
When I click a menu item, and use NavigateUrl property, it loades a page in the whole browser screen. How can I make it loades inside a certain region, in this case the update panel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the new page (the one that loads in the whole screen) inherit from the master page and have all content inside an `<asp:Content>` tag?

Comment: If this page is not associated with the Master Page, you need to go with an "iFrame".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is to use an `iframe`.

I personally am not a big fan of `iframe`s and would recommend that if you are truly looking for a "load in place" type solution that you research a more client-side solution than `ASP.NET WebForms using UpdatePanels`, such as jQuery/AJAX/Templating, KnockoutJS, BackboneJS, AngularJS or Ember.js.

Answer (score 1):

As a different option you can convert the aspx page into a UserControl. Then you can load the UserControl in the update panel.

If you also want to have an aspx page you can create a different aspx page that contains that same UserControl.